# Problem including an external JQuery into Django template

Tags: python, jquery, django

The template below has no problems if I run it inside the same html template. But if I put the JQuery code in a country_dropdown.js external file inside the static folder, and I include it like that:

```
<script  src="{% static 'js/countries.js' %}"></script>
```

then the following:

```
url: "{% url 'get-province' %}",
```

will not work.

It seems that the {% tags are not recognized inside external js files, even if they should. In fact the requested is rendered this way:

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/countries/%7B%25%20url%20'get-province'%20%25%7D
```

Obviously the %7B means { and the %25 means %. Therefore template tags are not properly recognized outside the template.

But, since I will use the same functionality and the same drop-down list in several places, it would be a very good practice to put the JQuery in an external file and include it when I need it instead of duplicating it in each template where it is needed.

How could I include the external JQuery without problems? I have included the complete template here.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <form class="" action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for error in errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger mb-4" role="alert">
                <b>{{ error }}</b>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        current {{ lang }}
        <div class ="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="mb-4">
                    {{ form.country }}
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <br><br>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="mb-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>{% trans "Select a Province/State" %}</label>
                        <select id="id_province" class="form-control" name="state">
                            <option value="----">{% trans "Select Province/State" %}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script  src="{% static 'js/countries.js' %}"></script>-->
    <script>
        $("#id_country").change(function(){
            var countryId = $(this).val();
            /* if country changes reset city list */
            //$("#id_city").html("");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'get-province' %}",
                data: {
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                    'country': countryId
                },
                success: function (data){
                    console.log(data.provinces);
                    data.provinces = data.provinces.sort(function(a, b){
                        if (a[1] < b[1]) return -1;
                        if (a[1] > b[1]) return 1;
                        return 0;
                    });
                    let html_data = '';
                    if (data.provinces.length !== 0) {
                        html_data = '<option value="-----">{% trans "Select State" %}</option>';
                        data.provinces.forEach(function(data){
                        html_data += `<option value="${data[0]}">${data[1]}</option>`
                    });
                    }else{
                        html_data = '<option value="-----">{% trans "No states available for this country" %}</option>';
                    }
                    $("#id_province").html(html_data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why don't you move `$("#id_country").change(function()` to **base.html**? In this way you would have access to it from every template where you extend base.html

Comment: I could do it but most templates will not need it. And it would not be a good practice to have a JQuery code available for ALL the templates when it is only needed in templates with a form involving countries drop-down lists.

Comment: In that case you may create a template (e.g. base_with_jquery.html) and inherit from base.html. Finally inherit from base_with_jquery.html instead of base.html where you need that function.

Comment: Yes I can do this perfectly. But this means that it is not possible to load JQuery code externally. I suspect it is only possible with vanilla JavaScript

Comment: No this will not work. Because in base.html I must declare a content block in order to include it. In base_with_jquery.js I must also include a content block, but it will be duplicated. If I have {% block content %} and then {% block jquery %} in base, then it's is the same than putting the entire JQuery in the base. It will be loaded in all the templates. It must be another way to solve this issue.

Comment: I didn't know there were an include directive in the block statement. I solved the problem with it.